# Use TfileUnarchive on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, talend

I have a talend job which is simple like below:
ts3Connection -> ts3Get -> tfileinputDelimeted -> tmap -> tamazonmysqloutput.

Now the scenario here is that some times I get the file in .txt format and sometimes I get it in a zip file.
So I want to use tFileUnarchive to unzip the file if it's in zip or process it bypassing the tFileUnarchive component if the file is in unzipped format i.e only in .txt format.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to break the file retrieval and potential unzipping into one sub job and then the processing of the files into another sub job afterwards.

Here's a simple example job:

[image: Example job layout showing how to conditionally unzip files from S3]

As normal, you connect to S3 and then you might list all the relevant objects in the bucket using the tS3List and then pass this to tS3Get. Alternatively you might have another way of passing the relevant object key that you want to download to tS3Get.

In the above job I set tS3Get up to fetch every object that is iterated on by the tS3List component by setting the key as:

```
((String)globalMap.get("tS3List_1_CURRENT_KEY"))
```

and then downloading it to:

```
"C:/Talend/5.6.1/studio/workspace/S3_downloads/" + ((String)globalMap.get("tS3List_1_CURRENT_KEY"))
```

The extra bit I've added starts with a `Run If` conditional link from the tS3Get which links the tFileUnarchive with the condition:

```
((String)globalMap.get("tS3List_1_CURRENT_KEY")).endsWith(".zip")
```

Which checks to see if the file being downloaded from S3 is a `.zip` file.

The tFileUnarchive component then just needs to be told what to unzip, which will be the file we've just downloaded:

```
"C:/Talend/5.6.1/studio/workspace/S3_downloads/" + ((String)globalMap.get("tS3List_1_CURRENT_KEY"))
```

and where to extract it to:

```
"C:/Talend/5.6.1/studio/workspace/S3_downloads"
```

This then puts any extracted files in the same place as the ones that didn't need extracting.

From here we can now iterate through the downloads folder looking for the file types we want by setting the directory to `"C:/Talend/5.6.1/studio/workspace/S3_downloads"` and the global expression to `"*.csv"` in my case as I wanted to read in only the CSV files (including the zipped ones) I had in S3.

Finally, we then read the delimited files by setting the file to be read by the tFileInputDelimited component as:

```
((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))
```

And in my case I simply then printed this to the console but obviously you would then want to perform some transformation before uploading to your AWS RDS instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am facing a couple of issue here.
The first is that I have a bucket on S3 suppose 'Analysis' and inside that I have a month wise folder like 'May2015' and so on. So the tfileUnarchive is extracting with the folder i.e in the path specified it is creating May2015/File.txt and while trying to iterate it using tfilelist it is not able to find the file.
Also here you have shown how to do it from local system but if I want to run it through EMR cluster then how do I achieve it.
Do guide me on that.

Comment: You need to break this out into multiple questions to keep them clear and concise. I'd suggest creating a new question linking back to this question showing how what you've done now after getting the above answer and then being more specific with your requirements (So the question title might be something like "Using tFileUnarchive on nested folder structure in S3") and where the above answer doesn't quite cover your new question. If/once that gets answered I'd then raise another question about how to apply that answer to an EMR cluster/MapReduce job.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the solution to unzipping the files and reading it.
Regarding my first query of nested folder structures,after doing some research I guess I have done it.I checked the include subdirectories option in tfilelist component and it seems to work.
Also if you have any idea on my second query do let me know.